# python3 configure script error - could not find pthreads

Tags: python, macos, cmake

I am trying to compile python 3.7.7 on mac os Big Sur.
Downloaded the source code from python.org
running the configure script exits on error

```
configure: error: could not find pthreads on your system
```

cmake version 3.19.0

gcc version

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Why do you not simply use one of [these installers](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) or a package manager?

Comment: I'm using bazel to build my python code and it compiles the python interpreter.